Searching for Images with Search Term
I wanted to write a custom key map that would allow me to search images using the given search term. I am using Vimium C for Edge.
I have written the following key mapping:
map gm openUrl url="https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=$s" url_mask="$s"
This is my idea :

I would search for something (say flower)

I would press the keystroke gm

The page should redirect me to the corresponding images URL using the search term. (so it should go to https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=flower)


Now the problem comes in the third part.
Instead of going to the corresponding image URL, it goes to this weird URL -> https://www.bing.com/search?q=flower&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&lq=0&pq=flower&sc=13-6&sk=&cvid=2AAC63E2C07947C785377C065336A32D&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl= - Search Images
I feel this is because the $s character is taking the whole URL in the URL bar, instead of just taking the search term.
Is there any way to truncate the URL? Or am I doing something wrong?

IMO bad vim emulation is not vim even less nvim; both tags are unnecessary and should be removed.
